# Line break in ruby in cgi

Tags: ruby, cgi

this is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sqlite3'
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html><body>Hello Stack Overflow<p></body></html>\r\n"

database = SQLite3::Database.new( "new.database" )
database.execute( "create table new_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);" )

database.execute( "insert into new_table (content) values ('this is a stack')")
database.execute( "insert into new_table (content) values ('this is overflow')")

rows = database.execute( "select * from new_table" )

p rows
```

This works but prints the rows in one line. I want to add a line break but I don´t know how.
html tag

doesn´t work, \n neither.

Can you help?

Comment: try taking a look at some HTML tutrial, since printing stuff after </html> is not such a good idea...

Comment: yeah maybe that´s the fault here

Comment: @r I don't think so... line breaks are <br> in HTML. Your data might be better displayed as a <table> with <tr>s. But all of that should come inside <body></body> only. I would think a language like ruby has some helper functions for printing rows from sql requests.

Comment: I don´t know if ruby has helpers but rails does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<br>` will do the work, since you are printing HTML.

```
rows.each do |row|
   print row + '<br>'
end
```

Comment: How do I have to write it? `p rows + <br>` ??

Comment: ´print row + '<br>'` doesn´t work either. Maybe its because of not being in the html-tags

Comment: `rows.each do |row|
   puts row
   puts "<p>"
end` works well

Answer (score 1):

From your question i got to know that you want to print the content of `rows` variable line by line,if it is then you can treat `rows` as an array variable and use `each` with `row`.

For example,

```
rows.each do |x|
   print "#{x}\n"
end
```

Try this if it helps you.